# Get a log of Files that a user has CheckOut in TFS

Tags: tfs

Anyone know how to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Team Foundation Sideckicks:
http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/

Answer (score 2):

Try the tfs command line. It will be something like tf.exe status /user:username.